# Qmail / Zend Mail - RFC 5322 compliant

Tags: php, email, rfc, zend

My company is getting spammed by itself, or rather by it's Qmail, we've got a few automated processes sending out e-mails with Qmail and Zend Mail.

I'm not a expert in either of these, (I know literally nothing about them), and the 'spam e-mails' are Qmail telling us that a series of e-mails being sent isn't RFC 5322 compliant.

Is there a way for me to locate what is generating these error e-mails? Or a place where I can find out what e-mails it's trying to deliver but can't.

This is the mail we recieve

```
From: MAILER-DAEMON@www.company.com
[mailto:MAILER-DAEMON@www.company.com]
Sent: 10. september 2013 15:10
To: company@www.company.com
Subject: failure notice

Hi. This is the qmail-send program at www.company.com.
I'm afraid I wasn't able to deliver your message to the following addresses.
This is a permanent error; I've given up. Sorry it didn't work out.

<user@mail.com>:
65.54.188.110 failed after I sent the message.
Remote host said: 550 5.7.0 (BAY0-MC3-F46) Message could not be delivered.
Please ensure the message is RFC 5322 compliant.

--- Below this line is a copy of the message.

Return-Path: <compnay@company.com>
Received: (qmail 25746 invoked by uid 0); 10 Sep 2013 15:10:02 +0200
Message-ID: <20130910131002.25707.qmail@www.company.com>
To: user <user@mail.com>
Subject:
From:
Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2013 15:10:02 +0200
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline
```

Comment: You shoujld be able to find the answer by looking at the qmail logs.

Comment: There isn't any (as far as I've been cable of finding.) I don't think that it's been enabled in the config file.

Comment: It might be helpful to capture one of the messages that get rejected *including all headers* and add it to your question.  Sanitising personal email addresses would be a good idea but even those could be hiding the reason for the rejection so if you can reproduce the rejection with an email address you don't have to sanitise, all the better.

Comment: If there are no qmail logs at all, you do indeed have a serious problem, with more than these emails. Apart from that, I second @Ladadadada's request for more information.

Comment: I have updated my question to include the entire e-mail we get back though I have omitted the recievers e-mail, I'm rather clumsy asking these kind of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `From:` header has no value. This is a pretty blatant violation of RFC 5322. Fix your application so that it provides a valid value for the `From:` header.

Comment: The issue is, that I don't know WHERE this is being caused, the site is old and quiet frankly impossible to get around in. Is there a way qmailer / Zend place where I can find out what's going on? i.e if I figure out how to turn on Error logging?

Comment: There may or may not be clues in the system logs, depending on how your applications are deployed. You'll just have to go look.